# How do I restore a file that is currently git committed

Tags: git, git-commit

I just started using git yesterday, and today I committed a couple files, but then for some reason they disappeared. They show up when I run the command "git log -p -2" in one of the commits I previously did, but I have no idea how to restore them to where they were originally.

Comment: [`git checkout <commit> -- path/to/file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemlttree-ishgt--ltpathspecgt82308203) ? The `checkout` command can do a number of things..

Comment: when I do that it says "fatal: invalid reference: rev"

Comment: Put in a valid commit/tree-ish thing, I changed it to <commit> and linked for clarity :)

Comment: What is the output of `git status`?

Comment: when I do it now it doesn't return anything.

Comment: in the output of git status it says deleted: path/to/file for  all the files that I need to restore.

Comment: Then it hasn't been committed. use `git checkout HEAD -- file1 file2 etc` as I say in the response I made a few minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it Is already committed, you could get them back from the commit before the deletion was committed. Assume that commit where they we're deleted Is `D`. You can do this:

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source=D~ -- file1 file2 # keep the pigtail
git commit -m "recovering files file1 AND file2"
```

You could do a `git commit --amend` if deletion happened in the last commit.

Original answer from 2018:
If you committed their deletion and you actually **don't want it**, you should consider resetting --hard (use with *extreme* care... many tears have come out of using it). If you actually haven't committed the deletion, you could just check them out of HEAD: `git checkout HEAD -- file1.txt file2.txt`.

Comment: please rather recommend `reset --keep` which does not touch uncommitted changes

Comment: After 5 years, I think I have better advice. Thanks for bringing this up .

Comment: I recommend quoting the pigtail while we are at it, might be erroneously interpreted by some shells